# Is there a way to use 6DOF for spring in blender physics?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, physics

I wanted to make a bone with an angular spring for animation,
But it seems there's only a spring joint constraint for length not rotation.
(Generic Spring)
But I found 6DOF for spring in game engine, so I assumed there might be a way
to use it in animation? Like from python console or something?
Please tell me if you know something about it. 
I aslo want to know how to make angular spring in blender physics
Thank you.